# How to avoid FATAL EXCEPTION in OkHttp Dispatcher after callback

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm getting this `exception` when performing ui actions after receiving callback from `OkHttp`.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
>                                                                                           Process: org.example.verificationserviceexample, PID: 20421
>                                                                                           android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads
>                                                                                               at android.animation.ValueAnimator.cancel(ValueAnimator.java:1020)
>                                                                                               at android.animation.AnimatorSet.cancel(AnimatorSet.java:366)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.drawable.RippleComponent.cancelSoftwareAnimations(RippleComponent.java:214)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.drawable.RippleComponent.cancel(RippleComponent.java:133)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.drawable.RippleComponent.enter(RippleComponent.java:100)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.tryBackgroundEnter(RippleDrawable.java:552)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.setBackgroundActive(RippleDrawable.java:290)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.onStateChange(RippleDrawable.java:270)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:735)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:18046)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:4090)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.drawableStateChanged(AppCompatButton.java:155)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:18115)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:8135)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.setEnabled(TextView.java:1609)
>                                                                                               at org.example.verificationserviceexample.MainActivity.renderButtons(MainActivity.java:146)
>                                                                                               at org.example.verificationserviceexample.MainActivity.onAudioStateChanged(MainActivity.java:170)
>                                                                                               at com.bssys.spitchmobilesdk.audio.SpitchAudioManager.publishAudioStateChange(SpitchAudioManager.java:123)
>                                                                                               at com.bssys.spitchmobilesdk.audio.SpitchAudioManager.stopAudio(SpitchAudioManager.java:83)
>                                                                                               at com.bssys.spitchmobilesdk.VerificationService.stopAudio(VerificationService.java:96)
>                                                                                               at com.bssys.spitchmobilesdk.VerificationService.stopEnrollment(VerificationService.java:57)
>                                                                                               at org.example.verificationserviceexample.MainActivity.lambda$null$0$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:60)
>                                                                                               at org.example.verificationserviceexample.MainActivity$$Lambda$3.onSpitchResult(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.bssys.spitchmobilesdk.VerificationService$1.onFailure(VerificationService.java:111)
>                                                                                               at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:161)
>                                                                                               at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

And this is the code that I'm using:

```
public void addVoicePrintFromSource(Pipe source, SpitchConfig config, @NonNull String speakerId, Callback callback){

        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return MediaType.parse("audio/x-pcm; rate="+config.getRate());
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
               sink.writeAll(source.source());
            }
        };
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
       .url(config.getServerURL())
                .addHeader("Accept","*/*")
                .addHeader("Connection","Keep-Alive") 
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);

    }
```

I'm using an OkIo Pipe to populate RequestBody with audio data

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't change the state of views from other threads, which includes OKHTTP callbacks.  If you need to, do it on a runOnUiThread block.  By calling setEnabled, you're causing various UI functions to be called that can't run on that thread.

Comment: You're completely right! I got stucked with that problem and completely forgot that OkHttp is a Java library and not Android library. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: a pice of code will help us

Answer (score 3):

Please add you build.gradle(:app) file this below code:

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this won't fix this error, the correct answer is the accepted one ;)